# find out $\mathrm E[X],\operatorname{Var}[X]$ using the characteristic function $\phi_X(t)=e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$.

Tags: probability

$X\sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$

I try to find out $\mathrm E[X],\operatorname{Var}[X]$ using the characteristic function $\phi_X(t)=e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$.

$(\phi_X(t))'=(e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)})'=(\lambda(e^{it}-1))'e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}=((\lambda)' -(\lambda e^{it})')e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}=(0-i\lambda e^{it})e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$

$ (\phi_X(t=0))'=(0-i\lambda e^{i\cdot 0})e^{\lambda(e^{i\cdot 0}-1)}=i\lambda$

But I have to get $\lambda$ where am I wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you have to get $\lambda$?

Comment: The characteristic function is defined to be $\mathbb{E} e^{itX}$. When you take the derivative with respect to $t$ and evaluate at $0$ you may indeed recover the mean, but do you see the extra factor you obtain as well?

Comment: Nothing's wrong: since $\phi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]$, $\phi_X^\prime(0)=E[iX]$. Think also about powers of $i$ when you work out the variance.

Comment: I thought I have to get $\lambda$ since its the expectation of $X$ but now I get that I have to get $\lambda i$ , thanks !

Comment: the step $(\lambda (e^{\lambda it}-1))'=(\lambda )'-(\lambda e^{\lambda it})'$ is wrong, you changed the sign of the second expression for no reason. Anyway the result is $i \lambda $